# Android lauchmode and single instance

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-launcher

I don't understand how to do my use case between the launchmode of activity and the flag of intent.

What i want to do :

```
A => B => C => B when i back B => C => A
```

In other word, i want to have a single instance of all activity in the stack and if i recall one of the single instance the activity go to top of stack (with reset or destroy + recreate don't have importance, id o my logic of creation in onresume so), exception for my custom splashscreen (but i resolve this one with noHistory for this activity "splashscreen").

I tried standard mode with flag 
`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` or with this `flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` but that don't have the behavior that i want.

So if you can tell me which **launchmode** and/or flag i should use for made what i want, i would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) seems appropriate in your case:

> `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`
>
> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause the launched activity to be brought to the front of its task's history stack if it is already running.
>
> For example, consider a task consisting of four activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of activity B, then B will be brought to the front of the history stack, with this resulting order: A, C, D, B. This flag will be ignored if FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is also specified.

If we leave out Activity D in the above description we get:

A, B, C (start B) => A, C, B

Which appears to be what you want.

Comment: I tried it and thats work fine but the things is that launch new instance of app at each call (when you click on button for show current app launch i saw the same number of mine that screen that i launch. One trick for this?)

Comment: Well i find solution just had to set lauchmode to standard with it (i forgot to change the singleInstance/singleTask and apparently that cause the problem).